# Find depth of node in tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am trying to write a function that returns the depth of a node in a non binary tree. I've been trying for the past few hours and getting nowhere so any help would be appreciated. I keep getting 1 as a result. I am searching the tree for the exact same instances of Person.

```
/** 
 * Return the depth at which p occurs in this BugTree, 
 * or -1 if p is not in the BugTree.
 * Note: depth(root) is 0.
 * If p is a child of this BugTree, then depth(p) is 1. etc.
*/
public int depth(Person p) {
    if (root == p) return 0;
    if (childrenSize() == 0) return 0;
    int d= 0;
    for (BugTree c : children) {
        if (c.getRoot() == p) return 1;
        int k= c.depth(p);
        if (k != 1) {
            d= 1 + c.depth(p);
        } else {
            return d;
        }
    }

    return d;
}
```

Comment: Unless you are searching your tree with the exact same instances of Person that are store therein (please edit your question to clarify), this condition `if (root == p)` will not work for you. Better to implement `equals()` in `Person` and use `if (root.equals(p))`. You probably want a null check on `root` too. Also, the name `root` is suspicious - is `root` really of type `Person`? Also, you method doesn't look recursive enough.

Comment: I am searching the tree for the exact same instances of Person. I will edit to clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do Level Order Traversal starting from Root node. Let the Node have a property called depth. In Level order traversal, when you add children, have their depths as parent's depth + 1. Level Order Traversal uses a Queue data structure and is pretty simple.

```
        1       Level 1 or 0
      2   3     Level 2 or 1
    4  5 6  7   Level 3 or 2
```

Level Order Traversal: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Algorithm:

```
LevelOrder(tree)

1) Create an empty queue q

2) temp_node = root; //with depth = 0    *start from root

3) Loop while temp_node is not NULL

    a) is temp_node the node needed? if yes print it's depth.

    b) Enqueue temp_node’s children (first left then right children) to q with child's depth = temp_node’s depth + 1

    c) Dequeue a node from q and assign it’s value to temp_node
```

Checkout Level Order Traversal: https://gist.github.com/yitonghe00/0b3ba3d3ad8dc008c1ebf30d0a9e8773V

Answer (score 0):

Using the name `root` for the data payload of a node is misleading.
A *sorted* tree could compare, and pick the right subtree - much faster.

```
public int depth(Person p) {
    if (data == p) { // data.equals(p)
        return 0;
    }
    for (BugTree c : children) {
        int d = c.depth(p);
        if (d != -1) {
            return 1 + d;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As you see it is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you return an `Optional<Integer>` rather than using an `int` with a special value that means 'not found'. That is (IMO) clearer and less error prone. Using Java streams the solution would look like:

```
public Optional<Integer> depth(Person person) {
    if (data.equals(person))
        return Optional.of(1);
    else
        return children.stream()
            .flatMap(ch -> ch.depth(person).stream())
            .findAny().map(d -> d + 1);
}
```

Note: I have used `Optional<Integer>` rather than `OptionalInt` to use the `map` method. It'd certainly be possible to use `OptionalInt` as well but the code would be slightly more complicated. If someone knows why the type specific variants don't have `filter` and `map` methods I'd love to hear it!